# Where do I find localStorage data in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

Is there a place in Chrome's settings dialog where I can view the localStorage data?

I'm on MacOS, but I'm looking for a browser based interface for localStorage (not via browsing the file system)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools

Click on the "Resources" tab and you can select "Local Storage" in the side tree.

[image: Local Storage]